# WebRTC capture NSCursor image cause memory leak

Tags: macos, memory-leaks, webrtc

I face the problem, when I use the module desktop capture of the WebRTC to capture screen and mouse. `NSCursor* nscursor = [NSCursor currentSystemCursor];` I found this line cause memory leak. That's a loop function in a thread, about 200ms to capture once.I don't know how to release the memory.

```
void MouseCursorMonitorMac::CaptureImage(float scale) {  
   NSCursor* nscursor = [NSCursor currentSystemCursor];

   if (nscursor == nil) return;

   NSImage* nsimage = [nscursor image];

   if (nsimage == nil || !nsimage.isValid) {
     return;
   }
   NSSize nssize = [nsimage size];  // DIP size

   // No need to caputre cursor image if it's unchanged since last capture.
   if ([[nsimage TIFFRepresentation] isEqual:[last_cursor_ TIFFRepresentation]]) {
      return;
   }
   last_cursor_ = nsimage;

   /*
    others
   /*
}
```

The fallow picture, I only remove all whithout `NSCursor* nscursor = [NSCursor currentSystemCursor];`

[memory leak example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BsD6.png)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue when I had `C++` project and it including `Objective-C` code. To resolve issue I needed add `@autoreleasepool`

Comment: I was calling `MouseCursorMonitor::Capture` from cross-platform C++ code, so to fix the memory leak on the Mac, I had to create a helper function in a util.mm file so I could wrap the call in an `@autoreleasepool` block.